# Receive a phone number when registering a WooCommerce order

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have a problem.
I have a texting system, which I want to send a text message on the thank you page after placing an order. Now the sample code in the plugin that we have created is as follows.

```
   public function thankyou_page() {
            if ( $this->instructions ) {
                $api_sms = new sms_meli;
                $api_sms->send_sms($to, 'Your Order is Accept');
                echo wpautop( wptexturize( $this->instructions ) );
            }
        }
```

Now I want to replace **$to**
Be the buyer's mobile number to send him a text message.

Comment: [The question does not show any research effort](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/341393/what-to-do-with-questions-that-dont-show-any-research-effort)

Answer (score 0):

You should get the order I think, something like the following:

$order = wc_get_order($order_id);
$phone = $order->get_billing_phone();

Maybe you can you an action with the woocommerce_thankyou hook:

```
function send_sms($order_id){
  $order = wc_get_order($order_id);
  $phone = $order->get_billing_phone();

  //do something
}

add_action('woocommerce_thankyou', 'send_sms');
```

Of course you should also check if the phone number is mobile phone number to avoid losing the message.